# I see a strange Icon when I load the system using GRUB and when I open about the system in settings, I see the same icon and it is not Ubuntu's icon

Tags: boot, settings, system-settings

I don't know if this is normal or not, but I am a bit scared cause I don't know if I installed a modified version of ubuntu. I just downloaded from the official website: ubuntu.com but I don't know why I see this icon and not the Ubuntu's original icon. I have Ubuntu 20.10, but when I installed the same version on a VM, I see the original icon, look the picture to know what I am talking about. Thank you so much for the help and for the answers, have a nice day and sorry if this is a noob question, but I'm a bit scared about it.[as you can see it is a strange icon and and I don't know where it comes from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NyMrJ.jpg)

Comment: That's the Ubuntu Budgie logo, you must have installed it by mistake. https://linux-documentation.com/ubuntu-flavors-what-you-need-to-know/

Comment: Thank You so much for all the information, How can I remove it?

Comment: EDIT: I just did it, I completely removed all about ubuntu-Budgie and now I know all the information I need about ubuntu's flavours, I knew something but not all that I need. Thank You so much for All, I really appreciate it. Have a really nice day.